# Similar to the last Joining two tables on columns that don't equal and summing 3 columns in the second table

Tags: sql-server, join

I have a equipment table and a mobile work order table that I am wanting to join, I am wanting to display all the equipment and the reactive hours. If there is no reactive hours for a certain piece of equipment then I want to display a zero in the rows where value is null. This is what I have below. It only gives me the equipment that has reactive hours in the other table.

SQL Server

```
Select e.EquipNbr, coalesce(sum(mw.MaintTech1hours + mw.MaintTech2hours + mw.MaintTech3hours), 0) ReactiveHours 
From MblEquip e 
inner join MobileWorkOrder mw on
        mw.EquipNbr = e.EquipNbr 
    and mw.DateTm between DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getDate()), 0) 
    and DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, -1, getDate()), -1) 
where e.DelFlg = 0 and mw.Category = 'Reactive' 
group by e.EquipNbr order by ReactiveHours Desc;
```

Comment: Based on your description you need `OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: outer join errors out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you test a value into 'where condition', your 'left outer join' is equivalent to 'inner join'.

Try this (SQL remained)

```
Select e.EquipNbr, coalesce(sum(isnull(mw.MaintTech1hours, 0) + isnull(mw.MaintTech2hours, 0) + isnull(mw.MaintTech3hours, 0)), 0) ReactiveHours 
From MblEquip e 
left outer join MobileWorkOrder mw on mw.EquipNbr = e.EquipNbr and mw.Category = 'Reactive'
                                and Year(mw.DateTm) =Year(getdate()) and Month(mw.DateTm) =Month(getdate())  
where e.DelFlg = 0
group by e.EquipNbr
order by ReactiveHours Desc;
```

Comment: I tried your example but it returns the same results

Comment: can you give an example of data in your table and an example of output asked ?

Comment: i have modified my query, can you test now?